# recommended method to add a *single file* as a subrepo to a mercurial repository

Tags: mercurial, subrepos

I have a mercurial repository `myProject`:

```
myProject
|- file1.js
|- file2.css
|- useful.js
```

Now `useful.js` is a file with a few useful classes in it. I use it in multiple projects and as such it has its own repository:

```
useful
|- useful.js
|- example.js
|- README
```

The idea is that other people can check out `useful`, have alook at the file and the example and readme, and if they like it, they copy `useful.js` into their own project and make use of it.

Since `useful.js` is used in a few of my projects, what is the recommended way to keep it in sync? There is a restriction that `useful.js` *must* live in the top-level folder `myProject`, i.e. can't be nested. This makes it tricky to use subrepositories (and in any case, then I'd get the other files like `example.js` and `README`).

The other thing to note is that the `useful` repo has a few branches: `default`, `version1`, and `version2`. My projects that use `useful.js` also have branches `default`, `version1` and `version2`. I'd like to make sure that whenever I switch between branches in `myProject`, my `useful.js` switches branches too. If not for that I could probably live with a symbolic link.

This situation doesn't seem particularly uncommon; how do others handle it? Just write a hook on `update` to check if I'm switching branches and switch accordingly? Plus hooks on `commit`, `push`, `pull` ? (basically replicate subrepo behaviour for the single file)?

cheers.

Comment: I guess I'm after SVN *file* externals in mercurial (I know you can emulate SVN externals to directories/repos with mercurial subrepositories).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to add only a part of a repository as a subrepository with Mercurial. Thus you can't add only a single file from a repository.

Even if your other repository contained only one file, you could'nt add it at the root level either.

You will have to find another way to include your `useful.js` file. You're mentionning hooks to do that, but I can't see a way to do it honestly without some kind of manual work. Personnally, I'll go with "simplicity" and do everything "by hand".

Concerning the branch switch, there's no builtin mechanism in Mercurial, but as you said you should be able to do that with a hook on update.

Comment: OK :/ I ended up just copying `useful.js` from `useful` and committing it as part of `myProject`. It's up to me to remember to keep them in sync.

Answer (score 1):

Given your use case, it would seem that you might want to consider using [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) and more specifically the [Twitter Bower Package Manager](https://github.com/twitter/bower).  This way, rather than keeping a copy of the external dependency in your repository, just identify it in the Bower config.

Answer (score 0):

Follow-up @krtek

Yes, in any case you can't have linked (with subrepo) useful.js at the root of superrepo, it **must be** inside subbir.

But - no, with *some tricks* your can get some iteration to requested result (branch-dependent useful.js and adding single file instead of all).

In order to achieve this, you have to re-read subrepository documentation ("any supported by Mercurial URL can be used for defining external subrepo...") and `hg help urls`, namely

> An optional identifier after # indicates a particular branch, tag, or changeset to use from the remote repository

and note **mentioning of branch**. I.e - *if* you'll have special branch(es) with known name(es) in repository of useful and have in this branches only single useful.js, you can define subrepo with these added data - *branch with single file* for branch in superrepo

This way you'll have different subrepo specification in each branch of superrepo, have to merge branches with accuracy (always save "my") or define special mergetool for .hgsub files

Comment: I'm confused. So how could I get the one file `useful.js` from my `useful` repository into my `myProject` repository as a top-level file? If I make a branch of `useful` with *just* `useful.js` in it, when I check it out in `myProject` I *still* get the subrepo as `useful/useful.js` instead of `useful.js` without the containing folder.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee - **you can't have** it in the root, I wrote it in the first sentence of my answer. I wrote **only** how to *minimize* file-amount and make file *branch-dependent*

Comment: ahh, I see, thanks for that, though without being able to have it in the root, I can't use this solution.